# Intersecting surface on pseudosphere

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

It is known what surface cuts a sphere resulting in intersections along great circle elliptic geodesics... this is any plane through its center.

What parametric surface cuts a pseudosphere resulting in hyperbolic geodesics?

EDIT1:

The image shows an asymptotic helicoidal surface and a surface of revolution with parametrization.

[image: PS Asympt $ Merdn Surfs]

Meridional sweeps:
$$ (\operatorname{sech} u \cos v, \operatorname{sech} u \sin v, u-\tanh u ), ( -2<u<2),( -2<v<2); $$
Asymptotic helicoids: 
$$ (\operatorname{sech} u \cos v, \operatorname{sech} u \sin v, v-\tanh v ), ( -2<u<2),( -2<v<2);$$

Actually I would like to see how the non-central parametric surfaces also play out.

This implies that the Chebyshev Net defined by Sine-Gordon Equation supplies all the hyperbolic geodesics that are. Their projections in the cuspidal plane do not match projections from either the Poincare model nor Klein's ; that bothers me.. Thanks.

Comment: If by a pseudosphere you mean the hyperquadrics embedded in general $\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$, then exactly the same result holds. You can find a proof in O'Neill's "Semi-Riemannian Geometry" (look in the index for "hyperquadric"). From your past posts, however, you seem to be using the word pseudosphere in a different way.

Comment: I forced the $z=f(v)$ into the meridional plane.Is it Okay? Does it work with Diffrl. Equn for non-central cases? I am referring to standard $\mathbb R^{2,3}$ At present I do not have access to O' Neill's text book :( ;

Comment: The picture you include does not look like the pseudosphere as embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$. It looks more like a partial embedding into $\mathbb{R}^3$. The pseudosphere in $\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$ is the set $$ \{ - (\sum_{i = 1}^p (x_i)^2 ) + (\sum_{j = 1}^q (x_{p + j})^2) = +1 \} $$ with induced pseudo-Riemannian metric from the pesudo-Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$.